# I did this problem but I got percents as the answer not two values. What did I do wrong?

Tags: normal-distribution

Suppose that the lifetime of a particular electronic circuit has a normal distribution with mean of 50,000 hours and a standard deviation of 8,000 hours.

You select a random sample of 25 circuits

1) 92% of all sample mean lifetimes will be between what two values (symmetrically distributed around
the mean)?

Comment: What exactly did you do?  We can't guess what you did wrong--you have to tell us! Note, though, that the question asks you explicitly to provide two *lifetimes*, so any reasonable answer will be a range of hours.

Comment: I am really sorry. I swore I added what i did in there. Yes i understand what I'm looking for but I just couldn't get it to work. Find the z-values allociated with 10%ile and 90%ile
z for 10%ile is InvNorm(0.1) = -1.2816

 
z for 90%ile is InvNorm(0.9) = 1.2816
---
Find the corresponding x-values using x = zs + u:
x(-1.2816) = -1.2816*0.2 + 0.8 = 0.5437
x(1.2816) = 1.05632

Comment: (1) Where did you use the 92% figure in the question?  (2) Where did you use the information about 50,000 and 8,000 hours?

Comment: cancel that last comment   so i did                                                             Find the z-values allociated with 92%ile and 8%ile
z for 92%ile is InvNorm(0.92) = 1.411

 
z for 8%ile is InvNorm(0.08) = -1.41
---
Find the corresponding x-values using x = zs + u:
x(-1.41) = -1.41*.08+.92=.8072
x(1.41) = 1.0328

Comment: ^ Not 92nd and 8th percentile. If you cut 8 percent left and 8 percent right you'll only be left with 84% of all sample means, while your question indicates 92%. Also, the formula you showed does not look like correct to me.

Comment: Also still not using 50000 and 8000 ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to find the z-value corresponding to $96\%$ which is $1.75$.
And $ -1.75<Z_0<1.75 $ must be satisfied where $$ Z_0=\frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} $$
where $\bar X$ is the sample mean, $\mu$ the population mean, $\sigma$ the population standard deviation, and $n$ the sample size.

The only unknown in the formula for $Z_0$ is $\bar X$. You should just set $Z_0$ to $-1.75$ and $1.75$ to find corresponding sample means.

Comment: Welcome to our site, Bob.  When you use $\TeX$ you need to escape keywords and composite symbols like "sqrt" and "sigma" using the backslash character "\".  I have made a few such changes to illustrate the commonest forms. (Right-click on any of them to see the $\TeX$ markup source.)  More help is available at the right of your screen at the time you are editing your text.